# IExtensible is not supported in structs or classes with inheritance

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have this class

```
[global::System.Serializable, global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"MarketDataEntry")]
  public partial class MarketDataEntry : global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible
  {
    // some other properties

    private float _EntryPrice;
    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(270, IsRequired = true, Name=@"EntryPrice", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.FixedSize)]
    public float EntryPrice
    {
      get { return _EntryPrice; }
      set { _EntryPrice = value; }
    }
}
```

This was working as expected. I changed the type from float to decimal for the EntryPrice property, and now I'm getting Exception message on this line

```
Serializer.Serialize(stream, toSerialize);
```

Exception message says

> IExtensible is not supported in structs or classes with inheritance

Error message itself is confusing, because I made no change but float to decimal. Can that change be reason for this exception message? And what should I check for to understand where problem comes from?

I'm using protobuf-net v.2.0.0.664 on .net 4.0

**EDIT**

Regarding Marc's comment, MarketDataEntry is a base class for another protocontract.

```
    [Serializable]
    [ProtoContract]
    public sealed class MarketData : ProtobufMarketData, IEntity
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public DateTime TransformTime { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(4)]
        public DateTime ConsumtionTime { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(5)]
        public int FailedToBeConsumedCounter { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

So what actually is being serialized is instance of MarketData, which inherits from ProtobufMarketData, which in turn contains property of type List, so I think that's where problem resist. List of MarketDataEntry objects, which contain decimal property.

```
[global::System.Serializable, global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"ProtoBufMarketData")]
  [ProtoBuf.ProtoInclude(10000, typeof(MarketData))]
  public partial class ProtoBufMarketData : global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible
  {
    public ProtoBufMarketData() {}

private readonly global::System.Collections.Generic.List<CoreX.Shared.Entities.MarketDataDefs.MarketDataEntry> _MarketDataEntries = new global::System.Collections.Generic.List<CoreX.Shared.Entities.MarketDataDefs.MarketDataEntry>();
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(10004, Name = @"MarketDataEntries", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
public global::System.Collections.Generic.List<CoreX.Shared.Entities.MarketDataDefs.MarketDataEntry> MarketDataEntries
{
    get { return _MarketDataEntries; }
}

  }
```

Comment: That is odd; I will investigate

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks, what's even more odd, is that after I got the exception I created small test project, with Person ProtoContract, which has decimal property, and I could successfully serialize/deserialize the Person object. Any clues where this exception can come from, what should I concentrate on?

Comment: is it possible that in your real project `MarketDataEntry` is actually part of a more complex inheritance model?

Comment: Locally, I've your class in a set of tests involving (separately) `float`, `double` and `decimal` - they all work absolutely fine. So far, I simply can't repro. I wonder if the issue is related to something I *can't* see - perhaps either the "some other properties", or another part of the `partial class`. But the code as shown: works fine

Comment: @MarcGravell - yes, actually it is a base class for another ProtoContract. I will update post so you can see inheritance chain. And regarding your second comment, I don't believe it is some other property, because if I revert my changes back, and have EntryPrice property of type float, everything works just as expected.

Comment: If it is a base class for another `ProtoContract`, then: it shouldn't work for the ***derived*** type. As per the exception. Is there a `[ProtoInclude]` here somewhere? To protobuf-net, there's a difference between types that happen to be subclasses, and types that express inheritance *in the model* (via `[ProtoInclude]`, or runtime configuration via `RuntimeTypeModel`)

Comment: @MarcGravell sorry for confusion, I've updated the post. From Wiki I can see that List<T> are supported, so again it comes down to the MarketDataEntry type which actually contains decimal property, and I tried it again, if I change it back to float, it works just perfect.

Comment: @MikeMoore did you ever resolve your issue ?  I'm having somewhat similar problem -- please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40518369/protobuf-net-iextensible-not-supported-for-inheritance

Comment: @MarcGravell you mention that `IExtensible` not supported for derived-types ... what about base-types ?  ( those that indicate their sub-types via `[ProtoInclude]` attribute )