# protobuf-net : IExtensible not supported for inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, serialization, protobuf-net

It does not seem possible to implement `protobuf-net` serialization for classes that define their sub-types via `[ProtoInclude]` and implement `ProtoBuf.IExtensible` :

```
[ProtoBuf.ProtoInclude(1000, typeof(DerivedClass))]
public partial class BaseClass : ProtoBuf.IExtensible 
{ 
    ... 

    private IExtension extensionObject;
    IExtension IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
    {
        return Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref extensionObject, createIfMissing);        
    }
}    

public partial class DerivedClass : BaseClass, ProtoBuf.IExtensible
{
    ... 

    private IExtension extensionObject;
    IExtension IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
    {
        return Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref extensionObject, createIfMissing);        
    }
}   


var baseObject = new MyClass { ... };    
DerivedClass derivedObject;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Serializer.Serialize(stream, baseObject);  // throws runtime exception
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    derivedObject = Serializer.Deserialize<DerivedClass>(stream);
}
```

Attempt to serialize throws runtime exception :

> {"IExtensible is not supported in structs or classes with
>   inheritance"}
>   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.TypeSerializer..ctor(TypeModel model, Type
>     forType, Int32[] fieldNumbers, IProtoSerializer[] serializers,
>     MethodInfo[] baseCtorCallbacks, Boolean isRootType, Boolean
>     useConstructor, CallbackSet callbacks, Type constructType, MethodInfo
>     factory)
>   at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.BuildSerializer()
>   at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.get_Serializer()
>   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value,
>     ProtoWriter dest)
>   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.SerializeCore(ProtoWriter writer, Object
>     value)
>   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Serialize(Stream dest, Object
>     value, SerializationContext context)
>   at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize[T](Stream destination, T instance)
>   at
>   ...

Specifically what is the purpose of implementing `IExtensible` ? and what are the consequences of not doing so ?

Comment: Are you implementing `IExtensible` yourself from scratch, or inheriting from the base class [`Extensible`](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/protobuf-net/Extensible.cs)?

Comment: It seems as though this simply might not be implemented.  Possibly the problem is that all the utilities in the [`[Extensible]`](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/protobuf-net/Extensible.cs) type use a single `int tag` to identify an unknown field, whereas for polymorphic types an array `int [] tags` would be required?  Your idea to re-implement the interface at each level in the hierarchy looks to be a plausible workaround - but it doesn't work.  Maybe @MarkGravell can confirm?