# Workaround for Protobuf-NET IExtensible Inheritance Not Supported

Tags: c#, inheritance, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am deserializing protocol buffer data using Protobuf-NET and am dealing with multiple Proto files that are identical but have slightly different extensions. Basically each Proto feed is 99% identical and then has 1 or 2 fields different from each other provided as extensions for each. So I ended up with multiple Proto classes that are 99% identical.

Logically I want to add inheritance to generated C# proto files in order to avoid 99% of redundant code parsing each feed. The problem is that I am getting the following error upon deserialization:

```
System.NotSupportedException
  HResult=0x80131515
  Message=IExtensible is not supported in structs or classes with inheritance
  Source=protobuf-net
  StackTrace:
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.TypeSerializer..ctor(TypeModel model, Type forType, Int32[] fieldNumbers, IProtoSerializer[] serializers, MethodInfo[] baseCtorCallbacks, Boolean isRootType, Boolean useConstructor, CallbackSet callbacks, Type constructType, MethodInfo factory) in C:\code\protobuf-net\src\protobuf-net\Serializers\TypeSerializer.cs:line 97
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.BuildSerializer() in C:\code\protobuf-net\src\protobuf-net\Meta\MetaType.cs:line 480
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.get_Serializer() in C:\code\protobuf-net\src\protobuf-net\Meta\MetaType.cs:line 372
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source) in C:\code\protobuf-net\src\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:line 802
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.DeserializeCore(ProtoReader reader, Type type, Object value, Boolean noAutoCreate) in C:\code\protobuf-net\src\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 718
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(Stream source, Object value, Type type, SerializationContext context) in C:\code\protobuf-net\src\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 590
   at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize[T](Stream source) in C:\code\protobuf-net\src\protobuf-net\Serializer.cs:line 68
```

So it would seem that this scenario is not supported. Now what's not clear is if this applies to IExtensible usage in the Base class or the derived class. Base class must remain extensible since I'm applying multiple extensions, but the extension / derived classes do not.

I have code similar to the one below taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40518369/protobuf-net-iextensible-not-supported-for-inheritance). *Now before anyone labels it as "Duplicate" - it is not because my question is completely different. While it's OP is asking about the purpose of IExtensible and consequences of not implementing it, I am asking about any possible workaround or solution for the above described use case.*

```
[ProtoBuf.ProtoInclude(1000, typeof(DerivedClass))]
public partial class BaseClass : ProtoBuf.IExtensible 
{ 
    ... 
    private IExtension extensionObject;
    IExtension IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
    {
        return Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref extensionObject, createIfMissing);        
    }
}    

public partial class DerivedClass : BaseClass, ProtoBuf.IExtensible
{
    ... 
    private IExtension extensionObject;
    IExtension IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
    {
        return Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref extensionObject, createIfMissing);        
    }
}   

var baseObject = new MyClass { ... };    
DerivedClass derivedObject;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Serializer.Serialize(stream, baseObject);  // throws runtime exception
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    derivedObject = Serializer.Deserialize<DerivedClass>(stream);
}
```

**Question:** how can I achieve inheritance with above described scenario? I am open to modifying the derived class, any other work around you could suggest, or even using another .NET Protobuf library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that there is a collision:

- protobuf-net implements inheritance in protobuf (which does not have inheritance) by modelling it as multiple messages (one per type) and a `oneof` at each decision point
- in protobuf, each message could have extensions
- but right now, the implementation of extensions in protobuf-net is per *object*
- so it would be unclear to which *message* you want to apply the extension

I have thought about extending the API to make it track the extensions against the logical *type* (which would map to the message), but this is complex and would take me time to add.

Most other protobuf tools do not support inheritance at all, so I doubt you'd find that a viable workaround.

So: that's why it isn't there; that doesn't really.givr you a workaround, sorry. The only "fix" here is "take the time to implement the complexity of per-type extension storage and retrieval"

Comment: Appreciate the response Marc, glad to have a definitive answer from the author. Also thanks for creating & maintaining the Protobuf-Net library. For my use case, since my issue is with redundant parsing logic rather than having multiple redundant proto classes (your generator tool makes that part easy) I think I will solve this by passing deserialized message object as “dynamic” to my parsing logic. Another thought was to use the OneOf library to switch on message types, but I think that will result in lengthier/redundant code.

Comment: I'm curious if its worth considering extending the API based on assumption that a base class is the original message and the derived class is the extension. I know this won't cover all use cases for inheritance, but it would cover "most common" use cases when it comes to Protobuf extensions, following the idea that there's only one original message and many possible extensions. Inheritance level with extensions could be capped at 1 derived class to keep things simpler.

Comment: @AlexVPerl I don't think that is a safe assumption. If we were going to change anything here, it would be to add a type-aware API - something like `IInheritableExtensible` that looks similar but takes `Type` in each method